# Dyamically created UserForm, command button, and textbox: not registering textbox changes

Tags: dynamic, excel, user-controls, vba

Note: First time posting a question about code- ever. I have no formal training in VBA, everything I have learned is through experience or on the web.

I am doing some work for an employer. I am creating a scheduling system in which I do not want users to have access to forms in design mode. So I am creating forms dynamically (I hope that's the correct terminology) through code. I create a user form via code, and add all controls via code. I have a click event on a command button, upon which user-entered data is stored and the form is closed.

The code is complicated (for me) and broken into many sheets, sub routines, and classes, but below are pieces of code put together into a few sub routines in a way that should explain the situation. In this routine, a form is displayed upon the WorkSheet_Selection_Change event. The form is composed of a textbox and a command button. When the command button is clicked, a message box appears displaying the text in the textbox.

The form comes up fine, and the click event "fires". However, events regarding changes in the text boxes do not seem to fire, ie. if the text in the text box is changed, those changes do not appear in the message box. If I stop the procedure before closing the form (before clicking the command button), and go into the newly created form's code and run the code from the form itself, everything works as it should.

What is it that is keeping the textbox events from firing when the code is written dynamically? Have I missed something? The code is provided below.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Call Add_Form
End Sub


Private Sub Add_Form()
        Dim VBProj As VBIDE.VBProject
        Dim VBComp As VBIDE.VBComponent

        Set VBProj = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject
        VBProj.VBComponents.Add (vbext_ct_MSForm)

        Dim myForm As Object
        Set myForm = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("UserForm1")

        Call AddControlToForm(ThisWorkbook.VBProject. _
                      VBComponents("UserForm1"), "CommandButton", 60, _
                      20, 135, 90, "btnSave", "Save")
        Call AddControlToForm(ThisWorkbook.VBProject. _
                      VBComponents("UserForm1"), "TextBox", 80, _
                      20, 90, 90, "txtTest")

        Dim Line As Integer
        Line = myForm.CodeModule.CountOfLines

        myForm.CodeModule.InsertLines Line + 1, "Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()"
        myForm.CodeModule.InsertLines Line + 2, "Me.txtTest.SetFocus"
        myForm.CodeModule.InsertLines Line + 3, "Me.txtTest.Text = ""Change Text"""
        myForm.CodeModule.InsertLines Line + 4, "End Sub"


        Dim NewButton As MSForms.CommandButton
        Set NewButton = myForm.Designer.Controls.Item(btnSave)

        myForm.CodeModule.InsertLines Line + 5, "Private Sub btnSave_Click()"
        myForm.CodeModule.InsertLines Line + 6, "  Unload me"
        myForm.CodeModule.InsertLines Line + 7, "End Sub"

        myForm.CodeModule.InsertLines Line + 8, "Private Sub btnSave" & _
                "_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)"
        myForm.CodeModule.InsertLines Line + 9, "    MsgBox(UserForm1.txtTest.Text)"
        myForm.CodeModule.InsertLines Line + 10, "End Sub"
    Call ShowForm("UserForm1")
    Call RemoveForm("UserForm1")
End Sub

Public Sub AddControlToForm(objForm As Object, strCtlType As String, intWidth As _
                        Integer, intHeight As Integer, intTop As Integer, _
                        intLeft As Integer, strName As String, _
                        Optional strCaption As String = "!%!@")
    Dim objControl As Object
    Set oForm = objForm

    Set objControl = oForm.Designer.Controls.Add("Forms." & strCtlType & ".1")
    With objControl
        .Name = strName
        .Width = intWidth
        .Height = intHeight
        .Top = intTop
        .Left = intLeft
    End With

    If strCaption <> "!%!@" Then
        With objControl
            .Caption = strCaption
        End With
    End If


End Sub

Private Sub ShowForm(strFormName As String)

    Dim objForm As Object

    Set objForm = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(strFormName)

    VBA.UserForms.Add(objForm.Name).Show

End Sub


Private Sub RemoveForm(strFormName As String)
    Dim VBProj As VBIDE.VBProject
    Dim VBComp As VBIDE.VBComponent

    Set VBProj = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject
    Set VBComp = VBProj.VBComponents(strFormName)
    VBProj.VBComponents.Remove VBComp
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to information from your question you want to fire event after someone exit Text box which name is `txtTest`. In the meantime you made code which created `exit event` for `btn_Save button`. Therefore you need to change this line:

```
    myForm.CodeModule.InsertLines Line + 8, "Private Sub btnSave" & _
            "_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)"
```

into this:

```
    myForm.CodeModule.InsertLines Line + 8, "Private Sub txtTest" & _
            "_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)"
```

**EDIT** After some comment below now I get it. So, change this line:

```
myForm.CodeModule.InsertLines Line + 9, "    MsgBox(UserForm1.txtTest.Text)"
```

into this one:

```
myForm.CodeModule.InsertLines Line + 9, "    MsgBox Me.txtTest.Text"
```

It seems that `UserForm1` could be a confusing one therefore you could set reference to the userform in this proposed way. That fixed the problem in my test code.

*By the way, your question is written very well. If you wrote this code on your own with some support from the web I can only congratulate you. :) Keep programming!*

Comment: Thank you for your comment :) While this was certainly not clear in my post, the '_Exit' event is tied to 'btnSave' because the form I will be using "parents" a few textboxes. In that form, each textbox makes a contribution to the output, therefore I want to trigger code on the 'btnSave_Exit' (or '_Click') event. However, even if the '_Exit' event is switched to 'txtTest', and a user-change is made in the textbox at runtime, the message box still reads the original (pre-change) textbox text upon the '_Exit' event. I need the message box to register the changes in the textbox. Thoughts?